# My script runs fine until I import gTTS. Why does gTTS stop my script from running?

Tags: python, kivy, gtts

The below script only runs when "from gtts import gTTs" is commented out. I have gTTS correctly installed on my system but it is not working.

```
#from gtts import gTTS #uncomment this line and the script will not run
import os

import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        main_layout=BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        button=Button(text='Tap to select text', pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5,"center_y": 0.5})
        main_layout.add_widget(button)
        return main_layout
    
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I am coding a mobile app that will eventually be able to read text out lout. So far, when you run this code, there is a window that pops up with a clickable button inside. However, when I import gTTS and run this code again, nothing happens. My pop up stops showing up when this additional import line is added. I expected it to import gTTS and run like it was doing before just fine.

Comment: which error the terminal got you?

Comment: However you can use another library [`plyer`](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#).